# How do you enable scrolling on small smartphone screens?

Tags: responsive-design

I have a responsive website using bootstrap and a bootstrap theme. The responsive features work well except on this page http://mtganalytics.net/cards on smartphones in portrait mode.

The page has too many columns so you can't see everything. However, the page doesn't scroll. How can I enable scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

At line 378 of http://mtganalytics.net/base-admin/css/base-admin.css you have

```
.widget {
position: relative;
clear: both;
width: auto;
margin-bottom: 2em;     
overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you either remove the overflow:hidden, or overwrite it for mobile viewports I **think** it will help.

Good luck